# I want to make browser remember the specific dom in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, dom

I want to store some dom by its class name. by store some dom, I mean all the div i want to discriminate have the same class name, but I want to use it later in if statement, like if this is clicked twice and that clicked thrice. it it possible?

Comment: Just use javascript variable to cache DOM elements

Answer (score 0):

You could store that data into cookies if you need to collect clicks visits etc trough the whole site.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/ is a jQuery plugin that can help you setup/manage cookies in jQuery.

To set up a cookie after "including" the jQuery-cookies use:

```
$.cookie("clicked", 0);
```

Storing the whole DOM does not seem to good of an Idea to me if you only want to check on how often a div was clicked etc. So lets just call the cookie clicked and give it the value 0.

Now you prob have some onClick functions just get the cookie value and iterate it with 1 once clicked like so:

```
var clicked = $.cookie("clicked");
clicked += 1;
$.cookie("clicked", clicked);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is jQuery function to remember (.detach) elements in variable, then appending them back to DOM:

```js
jQuery(function () {
    var save = $('.special').detach();
    $('button').click(function() {
        if (save.length) {
            save.eq(0).appendTo(".targetdiv");
            save = save.filter(function(i) { return i; });
        } else {
            save = $('.special').detach();
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zWkxt/)